# SOAPwsdl2java Error "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Part 'fault' of fault message must be defined with 'element=QName' and not 'type=QName'"

Tags: java, soap, wsdl2java

I m trying to generate java classes from SOAP wsdl but getting below error "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Part 'fault' of fault message '{http://source.xxxx.xxx}xxxxException' must be defined with 'element=QName' and not 'type=QName'"

I m using the below plugin to generate the code
`<plugin><groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId><artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId> <version>1.7.9</version><executions>`
Could you pls assist me understanding why getting this error and how to fix the issue and generate the Java classess successfully?